'05 Scion tC, bought used. 145k miles , unknown if spark plugs were ever changed. Should I change 'em?
No funky smoke colors, no issues, runs like a champ. Just don't know if it was ever done before or not.
Bought at 92k, car is now at 145k miles
Leave well enough alone or change 'em?

yes, it's better to change them, especially given the mileage of 145k miles and uncertainty about their maintenance history.

Definitely change them. Even if you pull them out and they looks okay, I'd still change them. Yes, it might cost you a few dollars (denaro, yen, rubles, whatever) to do so, but knowing the state of the maintenance you've done to the vehicle will give you peace of mind as well as help the vehicle to run as well as it can. Any maintenance you deem worthy of this should get your attention. These are things like antifreeze and brake fluid, too.
It seems nobody (even myself ... dang, called it out, didn't I) changes these very necessary maintenance items. Brake fluid should be changed every two years. Antifreeze every 5 years (or at least check the schedule on it from Toyota). Seriously, if you are at all worried about the plugs, since the vehicle is at 145k (whether km or miles) change them out and know that you have good plugs in there which will last you another 100k without issue. Any other maintenance item which you feel uneasy about should be done as well. (After reading a few forums, I guess your tC has a chain and not a timing belt, so you can probably leave that alone. :o)
The big difference in all of this is that if you get it done (or do it yourself), you know where the vehicle lies instead of having a lack of knowledge. I can tell you from experience, most people want to do right by their vehicles, but don't. Don't trust in what other say they've done, do what you believe you need to do, especially if you like the car and want to keep it for a while. You can never do too much maintenance ... well, you pocket book might tell you otherwise. Do what you feel is right, but changing out the spark plugs might give you that tweak in gas mileage you thought you should have, but don't. In the end, you won't hate yourself for changing them out, plus you'll have the added knowledge your car is taken care of until the next time it needs plugs.

Appreciate it. I already swapped out the failing water pump and alternator earlier this year, and flushed the coolant while I was at it. However I could not get the new serpentine belt on (too tight) and didn't want to pay someone to do it just right then, so I re- installed the old one. It has micro- cracks, but still works. Am I in danger of grave damage if the belt were to fail?

@Elcucuy feel free to ask it as a new question, there's no limit on how many things you can ask :)

Why not wait until they fail? From what I read that wouldn't be catastrophic; instead, you have accumulating issues of all kinds. Any downside to that approach?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - if you're talking about the plugs, there's three reasons. First, if a plug fails and you continue dumping fuel into the cylinder, you run the risk of washing down the cylinder which causes damage to the engine. At the same time, raw fuel is getting dumped into the cat, which will damage it as well. Secondly, this type of failure will follow Murphy's Law and happen at a time when you can least afford it. The third reason is as a plug gets older, it doesn't work as well, which will decrease fuel mileage.  None of these are catastrophic, however still not good.

The only real way to answer this question is to pull the spark plugs and check their condition. If the electrodes are starting to look worn then replace them, if they still have useful life then check the gaps are still good and save yourself a bit of money by using them longer.

I second the emotion. Plus, if they have never been changed or removed, it is past time to at least loosen each plug and re-tighten it. If you go much longer, the plugs' threads can seize in the head, which will damage the head upon removal. The smart money is on loosening to prevent seizing every 60K mi / 100K km. Combine that with your inspection and you're good to go.
